# Error while pushing with git (error: cannot lock existing info/refs)

Tags: git, git-svn

I've been working on a project with Subversion and we have recently decided to use git instead.

I used git-svn to create a new git local repository and on the server, I ran:

```
mkdir myproject.git
cd myproject.git
git init --bare
git update-server-info
```

I ran git update-server-info because I'm using HTTP.

On my local repository on my computer, I ran:

```
cd myproject
git remote add origin http://url.to.my.server/git/repositories/myproject.git
git push origin --all
```

Then I get this error message from my last command:

```
Unable to create branch path http://path.to.my.server/git/repositories/myproject.git/info/
error: cannot lock existing info/refs
fatal: git-http-push failed
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I solved my problem.

Actually, I needed to add my username and my password to the URL.
I fixed this with:

```
git remote set-url origin http://username:password@path.to.my.server/git/repositories/myproject.git
```